# Create a query that counts instances in a related table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have re-written this query about 20 times today and I keep getting close but no dice... I'm sure this is easy-peasy for y'all, but my SQL (Oracle) is pretty rusty. 
 Here's what I need:

```
PersonID  Count1  Count2  Count3  Count4
1         0       0       2       1
2         1       1       1       0
3         1       1       1       2
```

Data is coming from several sources.  I have a table People, and a table Values.  People can have any number of values in that table.

```
PersonID  Item    Value
1         Check1    3
1         Check2    3 
1         Check3    4
2         Check4    2
2         Check5    3
2         Check6    1
```

.. etc

So the query would, for each PersonID, count how many times the particular Value appears.  The values are always 1, 2, 3, or 4.  I tried to do 4 subqueries, but it wouldn't read the PersonID from the main query and just returned the count of all instances of value=1.

I was then thinking do a Group_By ... I don't know.  Any help is appreciated!

ETA: I've deleted & re-written the query many times in many ways and unfortunately did not save any intermediate attempts.  I didn't include it originally because I was in the middle of rearranging it again, and it's not runnable as-is.  But here it is as it stands now:

```
/*sources are the tested requirements
  values are the scores people received on the tested sources
  people are those who were tested on the requirements */

WITH sub_query4 (
    SELECT values.personid, 
        count (values.ID) as count4  --how many 4s
    FROM values 
        INNER JOIN sources ON values.valueid = sources.sourceid 
        INNER JOIN people ON people.personid = values.personid
    WHERE values.yearid = 2017  
        AND values.quarter = 'Q1'
        AND instr (sources.identifier, 'TESTBANK.01', 1 ,1) > 0
        AND values.value = '4'
    GROUP_BY people.personid
) 
SELECT p.first_name,
    p.last_name,
    p.position,
    p.email,
    p.locationid,
    sub_query4.count4 as count4   --eventually this would repeat for 1, 2, & 3
FROM people p
WHERE p.locationid=406 
    AND p.position in (9,10);
```

Comment: "I have re-written this query ..". What query? 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: If I understand the problem statement correctly, then your desired output ("here is what I need") does not match the data from the test rows you supplied - correct? For ID = 1 and Value = 3, you should get Count3 = 2 (because there are three rows with ID = 1 and Value = 2) - right? Then - can there be any ID's with NO ROWS at all in the base table? And if so do they still need to be shown in the output, with a count of 0 for all values? If so, where do the ID's come from? (It can't be from just that one table, since they don't appear in the table at all.)

Comment: Correct, that was simplified gibberish to make my point.  I will update it to look more real.

Comment: Updated post to include code as-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values` is a bad name for a table because it is a SQL keyword.

In any case, conditional aggregation should work:

```
select personid,
       sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_1,
       sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2,
       sum(case when value = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_3,
       sum(case when value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_4
from values
group by personid;
```

Comment: This worked too!  And it helped me to discover that value is being stored as a varchar and not a number, which probably accounts for a large percentage of my frustration to-date.  I tried using to_number(value) but the comparisons still didn't work until I changed the other end to '1'.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use PIVOT for this. Here is [Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c00ed/16)

```
SELECT "PersonID", val1,val2,val3,val4 FROM 
(
  SELECT "PersonID", "Value" from VALS
)
PIVOT 
(
     count("Value")
     FOR "Value" IN (1 as val1, 2 as val2, 3 as val3, 4 as val4)
);
```

Comment: Hmm the Fiddle works, but I get this (SQL Developer):  ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here
01748. 00000 -  "only simple column names allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 13

Comment: Ok nevermind.. I had table.field in my screen... when I took out the table. it worked.  Now to see if it holds up under the other constraints I need to build around it...

Comment: You need to Make columns upper case. That is what oracle natively supports

Comment: Oracle's syntax is going to drive me crazy.